# React native redux form initial values not showing

Tags: react-native, react-redux

This is my code for redux form. I have also set `enableReinitialize` to `true` and followed the react-form documentation.

I have hard coded the `initialValues` object just for testing purposes. But still my form is not getting initialized.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Body, Content, Title, Button, Text, Left, Icon, Right } from 'native-base';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import MyTextInput from './TextInput';
import { fetchProfileData } from '../../actions';

const validate = values => {
  const error = {};
  error.email = '';
  error.name = '';
  error.mobile = '';
  let ema = values.email;
  let nm = values.name;
  let mob = values.mobile;
  if (values.email === undefined) {
    ema = '';
  }

  if (values.name === undefined) {
    nm = '';
  }

  if (values.mobile === undefined) {
    mob = '';
  }

  if (ema.length < 8 && ema !== '') {
    error.email = 'too short';
  }

  if (!ema.includes('@') && ema !== '') {
    error.email = '@ not included';
  }

  if (nm.length > 8) {
    error.name = 'max 8 characters';
  }

  if (mob.length < 10 && mob !== '') {
    error.mobile = 'min 10 digits';
  }
  return error;
};

class SimpleForm extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchProfileData();
  }

  render() {
     const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
     console.log(this.props.initialValues);
     return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button
              transparent
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
            >
            <Icon name="menu" />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>Profile</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right />
        </Header>
        <Content padder>
            <Field name='name' component={MyTextInput} label='Vendor Name' />
            <Field name='company_name' component={MyTextInput} label='Company Name' />
            <Field name='office_address' component={MyTextInput} label='Office Address' />
            <Field name='email' component={MyTextInput} label='Email' />
            <Field name='mobile' component={MyTextInput} label='Contact' />
            <Button block primary onPress={handleSubmit((values) => console.log(values))} style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
            <Text>Save</Text>
          </Button>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    initialValues: { name: 'abcde@gmail.com' }
  };
};

SimpleForm = connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchProfileData }
)(SimpleForm);

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'test',
  validate,
  enableReinitialize: true
})(SimpleForm);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been struggling with this for some time.  I've never been able to get anything with props to work.  But I just need to some initial state stuff, so this works for me.  Hope it works for you as well.

----- This works if you only want to set the initial values once.

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'test',
  validate,
  initialValues: { name: 'abcde@gmail.com' }
})(SimpleForm);
```

Edit:  It seemed I needed to pass variables in. This has been able to work for me for variables set in mapStateToProps.  I think your setup didn't work because it is mapping state and props to the form, then adding reduxForm.  It looks like it needs to be the other way around.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    initialValues: {
      name: 'foobar',
    }
  }
}

export default (connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(reduxForm({
  form: 'groupForm',
  enableReinitialize: true
})(SimpleForm)))
```

Comment: you're welcome.  If it worked for you, please mark mine as the answer to help future devs looking to solve this issue.